Why is my new plant Avocado tree dropping leaves?
I live in Los Angeles. The tree was planted two weeks ago. I watered it every other day on the first week, then leaves started dropping. 


Picture would seem to show drooping rather than dropping leaves.  Welcome to "transplanting is stressful if you are a tree" Soil looks rather poor - might give it some compost as a mulch ring around it.

Also - is it being adequately watered - I know you said you water it every other day - but did you water it deeply enough - that soil looks dry (although its difficult to tell) - and it is very possible part of the problem is lack of water.   (Avocado's like being watered deeply  - but not being drowned - and avocado's drink a lot of water.)

I'm not as expert here as I'd like to be, but my educated guess is stress.
As I understand it, Avocado root systems are very sensitive to root disturbances - as in Transplanting an Avocado could damage the root system and make the plant sulk.
It also seems you had quite a lot of fruit on it. (I'd pick off those fruit/flowers so the plant can focus on its leaves and root system.
The problem is probably transitory, and with just a little luck it will make a comeback and be quite happy.

If your plant grows in a pot, it must be transplanted into open ground. I also have an avocado, and one day the leaves started to fall off. I am from Ukraine, the climate here is not suitable for avocados, but it can be planted in the ground with our severe frosts.

This can't be the cause of the OP's problem - Growing avocados in pots are not uncommon, and the question implies it was planted into the ground anyway.
